# Could someone please help me with this proof? Can't think of an idea

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Prove:
$$\sum^k_{r=0}C^{r}_mC^{k-r}_n = C^{k}_{m+n}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you. This is not a homework service.

Comment: Also from the same link: - Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. - Avoid the use of images. - Choose a good title.

Comment: Search for Vandermonde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:
$$(1+x)^{m} = \sum_{r = 0}^{m} C^m_r x^m$$
$$(1+x)^{m}(1+x)^{n}=\sum_{r = 0}^{m} \sum_{h = 0}^{n} C^r_m C^{h}_n x^{r+h}=\sum_{i = 0}^{m+n} C^i_{m+n} x^{i} = (1+x)^{m+n}$$
Comparing coefficients of x by letting $i = r+h$
$$\sum_{r = 0}^{i} C^r_m C^{i-r}_n =C^i_{m+n} $$

Comment: Please see the first comment, following the original posting.